# NullPointerException - access array from fragment in method called from mainactivity

Tags: java, android, arrays, sockets

I'm currently working on small program that will send a string to multiple servers. I'm calling send method from mainactivity, which in fragmentA(fA). It's working well, but I cant access to array of sockets, which is in fragmentA. It throws NullPointerException

That is my calling function:

```
//MainActivity
@Override
public void send(String text) {
    FragmentA fA = new FragmentA();
    fA.send(text);
}
```

and this is function that sends stuff out:

```
//FragmentA

Socket s[]=new Socket[100];

//onactivitycreate
for(int i = 0; i<s.length;i++){
    s[i] = new Socket();
}

public void send(String text){
    for(int i = 0; i<s.length;i++){
        Log.d("","Send i = "+i);
        if(s[i].isConnected()){ //there error occurred
        //sending stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I can access variables from this method that are not arrays though, integer array doesnt work as well.
Maybe there is another way to connect with multiple servers and send to them the same string.

Edit:
Ok, so I've moved sockets and functions to mainactivity, and it works, but I still wonder, how to make it work in fragment, how to add fragment via FragmentManager with no ip or tag (viewpager).

Thank you.

Comment: You show where the error occurs but absolutely no information about that line. What's `s`? What's `isConnected`? Full stacktrace please.

Comment: And anything related to send data to a server should be in an IntentService or handled by Volley. Otherwise you will block main thread and you will suffer an ANR.

Comment: s is my socket array, and I want to send stuff only through connected sockets

Comment: Where are your sockets created and connected? If you are only calling `new` for the fragment but not actually adding and committing it via the `FragmentManager` then it isn't going through its lifecycle properly.

Comment: socket array is filled by this `for` with `new Socket()`. Socket connects in another function in fragmentA which works properly. FragmentManager is a problem here, becouse I use Viewpager, and I dont have any fragment's id or tag. I was looking for solution, but i havent found one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a Fragment to perform tasks that are completely unrelated to the UI. You should move the code to a standard java class.

But I think the exception is thrown because you aren't instantiating the Socket objects. Based on the code posted, the loop is never executed

Comment: Loop is in onActivityCreate, so it is executed.